# Botman not listening to Dialogflow action

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am working on a chatbot with Botman. I want to integrate Dialogflow's NLP so I'm calling the middleware and one of it's actions. The problem is that Botman is not hearing it. I just keep getting this error:

[image: that's the only console error I get]

[image: This is my intent's action name]

[image: This is the way I'm calling the middleware]

This is my intent's action name
This is the way I'm calling the middleware
I'm using my Client access token. I tried calling the action different names like 'input.automovil', 'automovil', (.*), but it's still failing and I haven't found enough examples.

Comment: show browser error response in network logs, or check log laravel.log file

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://botman.io/) is not updated. `ApiAi` is renamed as `Dialogflow`

**Replace**

`use BotMan\BotMan\Middleware\ApiAi;` **with**
`use BotMan\BotMan\Middleware\Dialogflow;`

**and**

`$dialogflow = ApiAi::create('your-key')->listenForAction();` **with** `$dialogflow = Dialogflow::create('your-key')->listenForAction();`

Answer (score 0):

try changing your lines 27 to 33 the the below

```
$botman->hears('automovil', function (BotMan $bot) {
    // The incoming message matched the "my_api_action" on Dialogflow
    // Retrieve Dialogflow information:
    $extras = $bot->getMessage()->getExtras();
    $apiReply = $extras['apiReply'];
    $apiAction = $extras['apiAction'];
    $apiIntent = $extras['apiIntent'];

    $bot->reply($apiReply);
})->middleware($dialogflow);
```